# Performance issue

Tags: haskell, memoization

I am working with times series, `type TSeries = [(Day, Double)]`, but need to translate the first `Day` element into Double for further processing (eg plots, etc...).

Mapping the date range to a corresponding Double range [lobound, upbound], where the earliest date maps to lobound and the latest date maps to upbound, is a basic transformation. In order to implement it I need first to get the minimum and maximum of the date range. I ran into performance issue, but I am not sure exactly why and how to fix it.

Here is the code (the time-series is not assumed to be sorted):

```
module Main where

import Data.Time (Day, fromGregorian, diffDays)

type TSeries = [(Day, Double)]

-- time-series to (Double, Double) mapping function
toDbl :: (Day -> Double) -> TSeries -> [(Double, Double)]
toDbl mapX ts = map (\(d,x) -> (mapX d, x)) ts

-- Day to Double mapping function - fast
mapDays1 :: (Day, Double) -> (Day, Double) -> Day -> Double
mapDays1 (d0,x0) (d1,x1) d = ((fromIntegral $ diffDays d d0) * x1 + (fromIntegral $ diffDays d1 d) * x0) / diff10
    where diff10 = fromIntegral $ diffDays d1 d0

-- Day to Double mapping function - slow
mapDays2 :: TSeries -> Double -> Double -> Day -> Double
mapDays2 ts x0 x1 d = mapDays1 (d0,x0) (d1,x1) d
    where d0 = minimum $ map fst ts
          d1 = maximum $ map fst ts

-- example time-series
func :: Int -> Double
func d = sin $ pi / 14 * (fromIntegral d)
ts = [(fromGregorian y m d, func d) | y <- [2000..2016], m <- [1..12], d <- [1..28]] :: TSeries

-- speed test
main = do
    let mindate = minimum $ map fst ts
        maxdate = maximum $ map fst ts
        test1 = toDbl (mapDays1 (mindate,0.0) (maxdate,100.0)) ts
        test2 = toDbl (mapDays2 ts 0.0 100.0) ts

    -- print $ sum $ map fst test1 -- this is fast
    print $ sum $ map fst test2 -- this is slow
```

The test that I perform (summing the X axis, first, elements) is not relevant but it is simple and illustrates the performance issue well.

Essentially mapDays1 and mapDays2 are the same except that in order to get the proper scaling I need to compute the minimum and maximum dates externally and pass them to mapDays1, while this is done "internally" within mapDays2.

The issue is that mapDays2 is very slow compared to the mapDays1 version. I suspect that the minimum and maximum calculations are called many times (as opposed to once), but I do not understand why and I am not sure how to fix mapDays2 to get a performance similar to mapDays1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is indeed related to memoization. The problem is that you call `mapDays1` and `mapDays2` without passing them all their arguments, so those calls only create thunks.

### The problem

That means that the thunks only get completed inside the `map`, so the different calls to `mapDays2` can't share their results for `d0 = minimum $ map fst ts` and `d1 = maximum $ map fst ts` and **the maximum and minimum get re-evaluated every time**. One could imagine a situation where `d0` and `d1` depending on the last `Day` argument, in which case it would be incorrect *not* to re-evaluate `d0` and `d1` every time.

By contrast, it should be quite clear that `mindate = minimum $ map fst ts` and `maxdate = maximum $ map fst ts` need to be calculated only once.

### Fixing `mapDays2`

Although we like to pretend that `f x y = e` is the same as `f x = \y -> e`, it isn't under the hood. You want GHC to avoid making a thunk when passed all but the last argument. Just move the `d` over the equal sign. Then, the function you return will calculate only once `d0` and `d1`:

```
-- Day to Double mapping function - slow
mapDays2 :: TSeries -> Double -> Double -> Day -> Double
mapDays2 ts x0 x1 = \d -> mapDays1 (d0,x0) (d1,x1) d
    where d0 = minimum $ map fst ts
          d1 = maximum $ map fst ts
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work well. The solution is very subtle ; how does it prevent GHC to make thunks early?

Comment: Even if we pretend that currying makes all functions just take one argument, that isn't how it actually works (that would be horribly inefficient). GHC generates functions with as many arguments as you specify and figures out all the currying under the hood with thunks. So there is a distinction between a function that takes 4 arguments and a function that takes 3 arguments and returns a function that takes one argument.

Comment: "it isn't under the hood" the behavior here is likely due to inlining and subsequent simple optimizations (only functions with syntactically fully-applied right hand sides can be inlined), rather than something more spooky about how ghc treats functions.